# (Angular) event from one component to another

Tags: angular

I have a component nested into another and I want to make an event in father component to call a method that is on component child, I have understand that it can make with input and output, but I don't find tutorials where there are events.
This is my code line on the  father template, but the method "getSemana()" is on child component

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/menu/graficas']" (click)="getSemana()"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Ultima Semana</a></li>
```

Comment: In my knowledge, events bubble up, so an event on father will go to grandFather not to child, but yeah I may be completely wrong

Comment: As far as calling a method on a child is concerned upon an event on parent, then you can use an input property in child, toggle the the input prop upon the click event, in the setter of the input prop in child, call the function you want to execute

Comment: Okay, so I was reading about event bubbling and Capturing. Capturing by default is not supported by angular yet, so you may have to register an event listener on the child component's tag ... through `addEventListener..` **I really don't feel that you want the whole child comp to liten for click event**. You would be better off which an Input property.

Comment: By the looks of your markup looks like for path `'/menu/graficas'` you'll be loading the component that has the `getSemana` method in it. So I guess you can just call this `getSemana` method inside the `ngOnInit` of that component and it's all going to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want it the other way around.  Child components trigger functions on parent components. If you want to do it the other way, you can create a `getSemanaFlag` in the parent, pass that down to the child, the child listens for it in the ngOnChanges, then you can fire the logic. It would look something like this. You have very minimal code so I am going to give you a very minimal description. You probably don't want the setTimeout, but it the best I could think of at the moment for what you described.

**parent.component.html**

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/menu/graficas']" (click)="setSemanaFlag()"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Ultima Semana</a></li>
...
<child-component [semanaFlag]="semanaFlag"></child-component>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
setSemanaFlag() {
   this.semanaFlag = true;
   setTimeout(() => this.semanaFlag = false, 100);
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() semanaFlag

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.semanaFlag && changes.semanaFlag.currentValue === true) {
    this.getSemana();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in `parent.ts` define `Subject`
2. pass `Subject` from parent to child as `child.ts/@Input`
3. in `child.ts/ngOnInit()` do `Subject.subscribe(x => {some logic})`.
4. thus each time you call `Subject.next(x)` in parent it will execute `{some logic}` in child.